# Setting a property in VB6?

Tags: properties, vb6, connection-string, ado

How do I set the connection string value of this property?

```
Dim mdbDataStoreADOConnection As ADODB.Connection

Public Property Set DataStoreConnection(ByVal dbNewDataStoreConnection As ADODB.Connection) 
 Set mdbDataStoreADOConnection = dbNewDataStoreConnection 
End Property
```

I want to be able to set the connection string of this connection variable, for example:

```
mdbDataStoreADOConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};Server=localhost;Database=myDataBase;User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3;"
```

I am still learning VB6 and am unsure how to assign a value to this property?

Comment: Wow. Just now learning VB6? I assume you know that it is obsolete and unsupported? If you know, then good luck!

Comment: Yeah I know thanks for the helpful response. The company I work for uses it so I HAVE to learn it.

Comment: Just making sure you know. You'd be surprised, but there are people who don't know.

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is setting an object. What you say you want to do is to set a property of the object. You have a couple of choices with your existing code. If you already have a matching Get property you can access the `ConnectionString` property of the DataStoreConnection object.

```
Public Property Get DataStoreConnection() As ADODB.Connection
    Set DataStoreConnection = mdbDataStoreADOConnection
End Property
```

You would then set the `ConnectionString` property with

```
DataStoreConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};Server=localhost;Database=myDataBase;User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3;"
```

There is no error handling, and the code as it stands is likely to cause an error if misused. For instance if the DataStoreConnection has not been set, your variable, mdbDataStoreADOConnection, is nothing and attempting to access properties will cause an error.